# AngularJS 1.5 ngComponentRouter

Tags: angularjs, ngcomponentrouter

The `ngNewRouter` (now named `ngComponentRouter`) was supposed to be in 1.4, but was delayed and is now supposed to go into 1.5 (as I understand it). However, it's not in the [1.5 beta2 package](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2). I do see [angular1_router on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular1_router), but I don't see that built module included in the [2.0 alpha](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/2.0.0-alpha.46) packages either.

1. Does anyone know if the new router will actually be in the 1.5 release?
2. Is there a current build of the new router hosted anywhere? I managed to find a copy of the compiled js from a random plunker, but haven't been able to compile the source myself (issues with node-gyp & msbuild, still working on that).
3. Does anyone know of any up-to-date documentation or working samples on the new component router? The [best site I've found so far](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/02/19/futuristic-routing-in-angular.html) is pretty close (it says it was published in February, but it uses `ngComponentRouter` rather than `ngNewRouter` so it's clearly being updated), but the post still has things wrong - like it says to create controllers for the components you're loading for the routes, but I discovered that you actually need to be creating them as directives (optimally using the new "component" wrapper in 1.5) with the restrict set to "A" (that was fun to figure out).

Comment: You might try Github. Heres a discussion that includes a build from September to get you started: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the component router has been released. Here is the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

I'm not seeing any official announcements saying it was released yet though, so I'm not sure if it's supposed to be "official" or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the new router via npm with:

```
npm install @angular/router
```

For more information on the current API you can have a look at:
https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

It's for Angular 2 but the core mechanics of the router are the same, and it should give you some hints on how the API has been changed compared to the ngNewRouter.

Comment: Iam getting extraneous on npm for that.  Is that due in part to the angular 1 and angular 2 folder?

Comment: This might be due to your npm version. Scoped packages (the @ notation) need version 2.7.0 or higher.